# Linux: Linking Microsoft/CPPRestSDK via qmake

Tags: c++, linux, boost, linker, cpprest-sdk

I am trying to link cpprestsdk with my Qt Widgets Application via QMake and .pro files.
I tried using cpprestsdk in a standalone demo application with the following part in a CMake-file which works fine:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)
find_package(cpprestsdk REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE cpprestsdk::cpprest ssh crypto ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
```

When trying to convert it to QMake/.pro-file like so:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/cpprest
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost/filesystem
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost/system
LIBS += -lcrypto -lssl -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -pthread -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono /usr/local/lib/libcpprest.so
```

The project compiles fine but at execution throws following error:

```
symbol lookup error: <path> undefined symbol: _ZN7utility7details9str_ilessERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_
```

C++Filt reveals the undefined symbol to be the following function

```
c++filt _ZN7utility7details9str_ilessERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES8_
utility::details::str_iless(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
```

Now, `ldd <application>` shows me that libcpprest should be linked correctly and I see no unlinked dependencies.

```
libcpprest.so.2.10 => /usr/local/lib/libcpprest.so.2.10
```

Where did I went wrong here?

Comment: Info: Running Ubuntu 18.04, package libcpprest has version 2.10.2-6, package qt5-qmake has  5.9.5

Comment: If I, instead of using the path to cpprestsdk .so file, use -lcpprest, I now receive the following error:  undefined reference to `utility::details::str_iless(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

Comment: While I rebuilt my QMake project using CMake with above mentioned CMake commands, I would still love to see how I went wrong in my QMake approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed the sample [Getting Started Tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial)

With:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcpprest-dev
```

On QT creator in ubuntu 20.04 and I add:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/cpprest
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost/filesystem
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/boost/system
LIBS += -lcrypto -lssl -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -pthread -lboost_thread -lboost_chrono /usr/local/lib/libcpprest.so
```

from your previous post to the .pro file

it build susscefull